# How can I isolate the result of scipy.integrate.quad function, rather than having the result and the error of the calculation?

Tags: python, arrays, scipy, numerical-integration, quad

I'm trying to create an array of integral values that will be used further in calculations. The problem is that integrate.quad returns (answer, error). I can't use that in other calculations because it isn't a float; it is a set of two numbers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`integrate.quad` returns a `tuple` of two values (and possibly more data in some circumstances).  You can access the answer value by referring to the zeroth element of the tuple that is returned.  For example:

```
# import scipy.integrate
from scipy import integrate

# define the function we wish to integrate
f = lambda x: x**2

# do the integration on f over the interval [0, 10]
results = integrate.quad(f, 0, 10)

# print out the integral result, not the error
print 'the result of the integration is %lf' % results[0]
```

Answer (score 10):

@BrendanWood's answer is fine, and you've accepted, so it obviously works for you, but there is another python idiom for handling this.  Python supports "multiple assignment", meaning you can say `x, y = 100, 200` to assign `x = 100` and `y = 200`.  (See http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#first-steps-towards-programming for an example in the introductory python tutorial.)

To use this idea with `quad`, you can do the following (a modification of Brendan's example):

```
# Do the integration on f over the interval [0, 10]
value, error = integrate.quad(f, 0, 10)

# Print out the integral result, not the error
print('The result of the integration is %lf' % value)
```

I find this code easier to read.

Comment: +1, I really prefer to explicitly assign the results to meaningful names, otherwise it's too easy to get confused afterward